# Trying to get data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to find a way to get the temperature data from a website. No matter whatever I do, I am getting None as the output.

Here is the code I used

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contenturl = "http://www.awebsite.com/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(contenturl).read())

table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.findAll('tr')

for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
        print (text+"|"),
        print ()
```

I have been using BS with Python 3. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi: this is Python 3, the reference to `urllib.request.urlopen()` is entirely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the temperature, find the table row with the text 'Temperature' in it:

```
import re

temperature_row = soup.find(text=re.compile('Temperature')).find_parent('tr')
temperature = temperature_row.find_all('td')[-1].get_text()
```

Demo:

```
>>> temperature_row = soup.find(text=re.compile('Temperature')).find_parent('tr')
>>> temperature_row.find_all('td')[-1].get_text()
'85.9°F\n'
```

To get *all* the temperature data, I'd start looking for the header with the 'Current Weather' text; it is wrapped in a `<big>` tag (ick, deprecated HTML tags), then process all rows with two cells following:

```
row = soup.find('big', text=re.compile('Current\s*Weather')).find_parent('tr')
while True:
    row = row.find_next_sibling('tr')
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    if len(cells) != 2:
        break
    label, value = (cell.get_text().strip() for cell in cells)
    print(label, value, sep=': ')
```

This produces:

```
>>> row = soup.find('big', text=re.compile('Current\s*Weather')).find_parent('tr')
>>> while True:
...     row = row.find_next_sibling('tr')
...     cells = row.find_all('td')
...     if len(cells) != 2:
...         break
...     label, value = (cell.get_text().strip() for cell in cells)
...     print(label, value, sep=': ')
... 
Temperature: 85.9°F
Humidity: 50%
Dewpoint: 65.1°F
Wind: ESE at 7.0 mph
Barometer: 27.346 in & Falling Slowly
Today's Rain: 0.00 in
Yearly Rain: 11.49 in
Wind Chill: 85.4°F
THW Index: 87.6°F
Heat Index: 88.1°F
```

Comment: Wow... That actually did the trick. For some reason I didn't get any  notifications that my question got an answer. So I came up with a rather 'unorthodox' way of doing it. Definitely going to change that now. Thanks a ton...